# MySQL Insertion Query Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, insert

I am trying to insert phone records from text file into MYSQL table. The text file is in format.

```
0300152652
0300213231
```

I was trying to insert data into single column table blacklist with column name records with datatype set as `varchar(10)` from below given query

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'E:\\home\\test.txt' INTO TABLE blacklist Lines TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

and giving response as

```
Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'msisdn' at row 1
```

Comment: Show the schema for that table please. I bet you're using an integer type of some kind when you should be using varchar.

Comment: I am using datatype varchar(10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'test.txt' INTO TABLE blacklist LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (@a) SET msisdn=SUBSTR(TRIM(@a),0,10);
```

You need to change that manually if you change the schema, but it should guard you against some of the usual data entry errors.